# Issue with stepping through PowerShell history via up/down arrows

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

Suppose that you've executed the following commands in Windows Command Prompt respectively:

1. `git status`
2. `git difftool`
3. `git commit -a -m "foo bar"`
4. `git push`

So the last command you've executed is the 4th one. Now you press the up arrow 4 times and get `git status` and press `Enter` to execute it. If you press the down arrow after that, you'll get `git difftool` (The next item following `git status`).

I'm very used to this way that Windows Command Prompt history works. However this feature is not present in Windows PowerShell. Pressing the up arrow always starts from the most recent command in history. Even if you execute a command from the history, pressing the down arrow afterwards gives nothing. You still have to press the up arrow and start from the beginning.

Is there any option to change this and make it the same with the Windows Command Prompt?

Comment: I am pretty sure you can do it by writing an own function involving get-histroy, invoke-history and some key binding. Also check technet script center and powershell gallery for similar ideas

Comment: Well, I found out that the problem possibly isn't related to PowerShell at all. I am using a script ([posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)) that is executed during PowerShell startup. When I removed the script everything went back to normal. I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/271) on github.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't related to posh-git, either. I frantically uninstalled modules and removed keys from regedit and one of those steps fixed it.